# Directive which toggles focus between two input fields

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a `directive` that would "control" two input boxes (there will be several of these directives on a page created with ng-repeat). The functionality that I can't find a solution for is `focus`.

Input boxes need to switch focus between them in each directive (ie. once I select one input box and press enter, focus needs to go to it's "sibling" input, press enter there and focus goes back to first input etc.). Focus never leaves a directive (ie. one of the two input boxes) unless I select another input in another directive.

Is there any elegant AngularJS solution for this behavior? Or, if not, is there any solution not involving jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do it is by binding a listener on `keypress`, which will `$broadcast` the event. The same directive can listen for that event, matching to make sure it's not the same element who broadcasted the event before `focus`ing itself.

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    scope: true, // necessary for use with ng-repeat
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$on('enter', function($event, argElem){
        if (elem !== argElem) elem[0].focus();
      });
      elem.on('keypress', function($event){
        if ($event.keyCode === 13) {
          scope.$parent.$broadcast('enter', elem);
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

**Note:** Updated from original response to allow for use with ng-repeat

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wah0gsGuoqk0J5GA8cy0?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

[ASSOCIATED SAMPLE with ng-repeat usage](http://plnkr.co/edit/AokazxfSt70onD8YLG9e?p=preview)

You can create a directive that will accept the `id` of the element that you can focus when you press enter. Simply use the `document.getElementBy` or `$document[0].getElementById`(for testing purposes) to get the element to be focused. Bind an event `keypress` to the current element context of your directive and trigger an element focus when you press enter.

e.g.

**JAVSCRIPT**

```
.directive('simpleNextFocus', function(/*$document*/) {
  return function(scope, elem, attr) {
    if(attr.simpleNextFocus) {
      elem.on('keydown', function(e) {
          if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            // $document[0].getElementById(attr.simpleNextFocus).focus();
            document.getElementById(attr.simpleNextFocus).focus();
          }
        });
    }
  };
})
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="input-1" simple-next-focus="input-2">
<input type="text" id="input-2" simple-next-focus="input-1">
```